# How to restore a "zeroed USB flash drive"?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I'm having a problem with a USB flash drive that was probably corrupted.

The error I got from Thunar (or Nautilus) was something like "Input / output error".
First I ran `lsblk` command to find out in which drive on the system was my pen drive. The output I got was: `/ dev / sda1`.

So I tried to restore the pen drive (the data that was on it did not matter to me) using the following command: `sudo fsck / dev / sda1`, but it did not work.

As this did not work, I decided to reset the USB drive with `sudo dd if = / dev / zero of = / dev / sda` command, then re-create the data partition with`sudo mkfs.msdos -I -f 2 / dev / sda1`.

The problem happened when I tried to use the command `sudo dd if = / dev / zero of = / dev / sda`, because it returned an error similar to what I got from file explorers (input / output error). After that, I can no longer access, or even list, the drive on my PC. It does not appear even with the `lsblk` command.

Is there any way to recover the flash drive? Even if it is necessary to re-write its firmware, or something like ...

Comment: This link may help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, make it work again: [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

I had a time when Ubuntu corrupted a flash drive, probably when I was trying to rename it.  At that time, I took the flash drive to a windows system then formatted it. The previous data was lost.